# play/stop mediaplayer not working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i have a media player with tracks on ASSETS folder, i want to make a start/stop button for each song. I'm able to play it but if i click the button again it won't stop the music, it will start another one without stopping the first one :s.

Here is the code i'm using right now:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {   

        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("4.mp3");
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            player.prepare();
            if(player.isPlaying()){
                player.stop();
            } else {
                player.start();
            }
            } 
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {    } 
        catch (IllegalStateException e) { } 
        catch (IOException e) { }

    }
```

edit 1 :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    player = new MediaPlayer();

    TextView sound4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cancionCuatro);
    sound4.setOnClickListener(soundFour);

    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("4.mp3");
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
        player.prepare();
        } 
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {    } 
    catch (IllegalStateException e) { } 
    catch (IOException e) { }

}

OnClickListener soundFour = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {   

        if(player.isPlaying()){
            player.stop();
        } else {
            player.start();
        }


    }
};
```

LogCat: 
start called in state 0
error (-38 , 0)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your calling

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
```

this is creating a new instance of mediaPlayer rather than referencing the same one to test if something is already playing and able to stop it.
Move your new MediaPlayer() outside of onClick and it should behave itself.

Comment: i tried! it plays and stop fine BUT it wont play again :(

take a look at edited code i have

Answer (score 0):

```
try {if(player.isPlaying()){player.stop();} else {player.start();}if(player!=null) player.release();AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("4.mp3");player = new MediaPlayer();player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());player.prepare(); } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {} catch (IllegalStateException e) {} catch (IOException e) { }
```